# What is the difference between Lavf58.29.100 and Lavc58.134.100 eac3 encoding using H265 in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, python, video-conversion, encoding

What is the difference between Lavf58.29.100 and Lavc58.134.100 eac3 encoding using H265 in ffmpeg?

I created a mkv file using ffmpeg and handbrake software but both using different encoding, handbrake uses Lavf58.29.100 and ffmpeg is using Lavc58.134.100 eac3 how can i tell ffmpeg to use Lavf58.29.100 same as handbrake?

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 28 -tag:v hvc1 -c:a eac3 -b:a 224k out.mkv
```

Handbrake video ffprobe:

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "hevc",
            "codec_long_name": "H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "coded_width": 1280,
            "coded_height": 720,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 93,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 23,
            "start_time": "0.023000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "DURATION": "00:01:49.823000000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "44100",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "title": "Stereo",
                "DURATION": "00:01:49.876000000"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "0.mkv",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "matroska,webm",
        "format_long_name": "Matroska / WebM",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "109.876000",
        "size": "30483436",
        "bit_rate": "2219479",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "title": "0",
            "creation_time": "2021-07-13T14:44:04.000000Z",
            "ENCODER": "Lavf58.29.100"
        }
    }
}
```

ffmpeg video ffprobe:

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "hevc",
            "codec_long_name": "H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "coded_width": 1920,
            "coded_height": 1080,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 120,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "field_order": "progressive",
            "refs": 1,
            "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "HANDLER_NAME": "ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.",
                "VENDOR_ID": "[0][0][0][0]",
                "ENCODER": "Lavc58.134.100 libx265",
                "DURATION": "00:01:49.806000000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "eac3",
            "codec_long_name": "ATSC A/52B (AC-3, E-AC-3)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "44100",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "dmix_mode": "-1",
            "ltrt_cmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "ltrt_surmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "loro_cmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "loro_surmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "bit_rate": "223715",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "HANDLER_NAME": "ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.",
                "VENDOR_ID": "[0][0][0][0]",
                "ENCODER": "Lavc58.134.100 eac3",
                "DURATION": "00:01:49.854000000"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "out.mkv",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "matroska,webm",
        "format_long_name": "Matroska / WebM",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "109.854000",
        "size": "25218291",
        "bit_rate": "1836495",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "COMPATIBLE_BRANDS": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
            "MAJOR_BRAND": "isom",
            "MINOR_VERSION": "512",
            "ENCODER": "Lavf58.76.100"
        }
    }
}
```

Also i tried ffmpeg-python package but on using H265 i am getting an error:

```
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('0.mp4')
    .filter('fps', fps=25, round='up')
    .output('out.mkv', format='h265')
    .run()
)
```

error i am getting:

```
Requested output format 'h265' is not a suitable output format
out.mkv: Invalid argument
```

Comment: What's the reason you're asking this? Is there an actual problem with Lavc/Lavf that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @user1686 When i try to upload the video to some site, the handbrake video does not give any error but when i try to upload by creating using ffmpeg it gives an encoding error.

Comment: Are you sure that's not because of the difference in audio codecs (AAC in one, but E-AC3 in another)? Most sites support AAC, but AC3 is a completely different thing.

Comment: At first i tried aac that didn't worked so i was experimenting with other options  somehow i put here ac3

I used hits one: ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 28 -tag:v hvc1 -c:a aac -b:a 224k out.mkv

Which is showing: 
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Can you name the site you are trying to upload to so we can try it ourselves and help you figure out the actual problem?

Comment: @llogan Why do you state XY problem i don't understand? i can't tell you the site as even i don't know, i created the video for a friend he said that if he is using handlebrake video then he is able to upload it but when he tries my video then he is getting encoding error.

Comment: @kup From the link, "The XY problem is a communication problem in which the person asking for help obscures the real issue, *X*, because instead of asking directly about issue *X*, they ask how to solve a secondary issue, *Y*, which they believe will allow them to resolve issue *X*. However, resolving issue *Y* often does not resolve issue *X*, or is a poor way to resolve it. The obscuring of the real issue and the introduction of the potentially strange secondary issue can lead to the person trying to help having unnecessary difficulties in communication and/or offering poor solutions."

Comment: @kup Your real question should be something like, "Why do videos from Handbrake work, but ffmpeg videos do not for uploading to foo.com?" The answer to "What is the difference between Lavf58.29.100 and Lavc58.134.100 eac3 encoding using H265 in ffmpeg?", is "Handbrake is using FFmpeg 4.2.4, and you are using FFmpeg 4.4 & Handbrake is outputting AAC and you are outputting AC-3", which I don't think would be satisfactory for you.